# Removing Ant logging prefix when running via Gradle

Tags: gradle, ant

Is it possible to remove the logging prefix added for Ant when importing its tasks into Gradle?

Here is the example from the official documentation:

- build.gradle

  ```
  ant.importBuild 'build.xml'
  ```
- build.xml

  ```
  <project>
      <target name="hello">
          <echo>Hello, from Ant</echo>
      </target>
  </project>
  ```

Output of `gradle hello`:

```
> gradle hello
:hello
[ant:echo] Hello, from Ant

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1 secs
```

Instead of this, would it be possible to have the following?

```
> gradle hello
:hello
Hello, from Ant

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1 secs
```

Ideally, the solution would also fix problems with other Ant messages such as `[ant:input]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend creating your own custom gradle logger where you can control what is logged to the console.

Check this out for more information: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html#sec:changing_what_gradle_logs

Comment: That's unfortunately what I was afraid of... I thought there would be an easy way to configure the AntLoggingAdapter but it looks like not. Thank you!